# How to open new tabs, switch tabs and close tabs with selenium on chrome after update removed sending shortcuts

Tags: selenium, tabs, selenium-chromedriver

There are two parts of switching tabs on chrome (and possibly other drivers too).
You first have to switch the context that the driver is working on, and in my case I also have to change the view so that a certain tab is focused.

You use to be able to just send the short cut keys (ctrl + tab, ctrl + t, etc) to manage switching the views, however that was changed recently.

After causing me a headache for this, and not really finding any good answers to fix this, I came up with some work arounds.

Answer (score 0):

**Opening**

You use to be able to create tabs on chrome by sending keys the shortcut to the page using the driver. However, it appears that doesn't work any more. Opening tabs in an alternate way is actually fairly easy, by using some Javascript:

```
((JavascriptExecutor)webdriver).executeScript("window.open();");
```

You then have to switch the context to the new window you just opened. You do this by using the webdriver.switchTo() method (plenty of documentation on this)

**Switching**

Another challenge that I faced was switching tabs after the chrome update made it impossible to just use shortcuts. I originally tried using Javascript to give the window a name like:

```
window.name = 'foo'
```

And then on a different tab you could do:

```
window.open('', 'foo')
```

and it would switch tabs correctly. However the issue with that it would work fine when you are sending it via console, but for whatever reason it would not work when sending it through the JavascriptExecutor.

I found a work around however. It is kind of hacky, but I do not see an alternative as of now. First you want to switch the context to whatever tab you want to be on using the window handles (again plenty of other posts explain how to do this, so I will not go into detail how to get the correct handle) doing this:

```
webdriver.switchTo().window(windowHandle);
```

This makes it so now the webdriver is on that tabs context. Then to actually switch the view so that it is synchronized with the context you have to do a bit of a hack. What you do is you open an alert on the context you want to switch views to, and then close the alert. This happens fairly quick so you will not even see the alert open.

```
((JavascriptExecutor) webdriver()).executeScript("window.alert('Horrible hack to switch tabs')");
webDriver().switchTo().alert().accept();
```

**Closing**

Closing is actually very easy. All you do is:

```
webdriver.close();
```